$(n + 1)$-cyclical monotonicity implies cyclical monotonicity in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Say a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $N$-cyclically monotone if for any $x_1, \dots, x_{N + 1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_1 = x_{N + 1},$ it holds that
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i = 1}^{N}
    x_{i + 1}^\prime
    (f (x_{i + 1}) - f (x_i))
    \geq
    0
    .
\end{align}
A function $f$ is cyclically monotone if it is $N$-cyclically monotone for every $N.$
In p.500 of Rockafellar (1966) "Characterization of the subdifferentials of convex functions", he conjectures that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is cyclically monotone if it is $(n + 1)$-cyclically monotone.
This is a very natural question, but I cannot find a reference of the proof.
Is this proven somewhere?

The rotation by $\pi/n$ on $\mathbb R^2$ is $n$-cyclically monotone but not $(n+1)$-cyclically monotone as argued in Example 4.6 of
Sedi Bartz, Heinz H. Bauschke, Jonathan M. Borwein, Simeon Reich, Xianfu Wang:
Fitzpatrick functions, cyclic monotonicity and Rockafellar’s antiderivative,
Nonlinear Analysis: Theory, Methods & Applications,
Volume 66, Issue 5,
2007,
Pages 1198-1223,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.na.2006.01.013.
